# TTNavigator does not work when used in DDMenuController's leftController

Tags: ios, ios5, ttnavigator

so, I tried creating a project using [this awesome DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController) and set a list menu controller in the left, with just datasource of three20's items, like this:

```
[section addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Groups" 
                                             URL:@"tt://groups"]];

[section addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Friends" 
                                             URL:@"tt://friends"]];

[section addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Updates" 
                                             URL:@"tt://updates"]];
```

and these url's i set in the URL Map as Shared View Controllers.

The problem here is nothing happens when i tap on the cell which should basically just push to a specified view controller,

But when i tried setting my right controller the same controller with my left controller, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt notice that DDMenuController overided

```
(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                animated:(BOOL)animated
```

so i just add some codes to enable pushing in left view controller:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated {

   //DDMenuController code here...


  else {
     [self showRootController:YES];
     [super pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
  }
}
```